# split array into range from negative to positive

Tags: javascript, arrays

currently I have an array `levels` containing other arrays called `level` and these ones contain `stages`.

I want to map all objects within a level with a new property called `position`. This position returns the distance from the center of the array. By center I mean the *length / 2*.

If the arrays length is even I want the following range

> ... -3.5 , -2.5 , -1.5 , -0.5 , 0.5 , 1.5 , 2.5 , 3.5 ...

If the arrays length is not even I want the following range

> ... -4 , -3 , -2 , -1 , 0 , 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 ...

I started creating this

```js
const distanceLevels = [
  [{
    "id": 1
  }, {
    "id": 8
  }],
  [{
    "id": 2
  }],
  [{
    "id": 3
  }, {
    "id": 4
  }, {
    "id": 5
  }, {
    "id": 7
  }],
  [{
    "id": 6
  }]
];

function getViewLevels() {
  const viewLevels = []; // the new array as the result

  distanceLevels.forEach(level => { // one level containing the stages
    const levelLength = level.length;
    const halfLevelLength = levelLength * 0.5;
    const levelLengthIsEven = levelLength % 2 == 0;

    let viewLevel = []; // the mapped level

    if (levelLengthIsEven) {
      addViewStage(viewLevel, level[Math.floor(halfLevelLength)], 0);
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < halfLevelLength; i++) {
      let rightPosition = i - halfLevelLength;
      let leftPosition = i;
      let leftStageIndex = i;

      if (levelLengthIsEven) {
        leftPosition++;
        leftStageIndex += Math.floor(halfLevelLength) + 1;
      } else {
        rightPosition += 0.5;
        leftPosition += 0.5;
        leftStageIndex += halfLevelLength;
      }

      addViewStage(viewLevel, level[i], rightPosition);
      addViewStage(viewLevel, level[leftStageIndex], leftPosition);
    }

    viewLevel = viewLevel.sort((a, b) => a.position > b.position); // sort the result by their position, means from negative to positive
    viewLevels.push(viewLevel); // add this new view level
  });

  console.log(viewLevels); // <---- result here!
}

function addViewStage(viewLevel, stage, position) { // push a new element to the array
  viewLevel.push({
    stage: stage,
    position: position
  });
}

getViewLevels();
```

This is the result I get

[image: result]

I really struggle with the math. All I want to do is to map each object in level from

*stage* (object)

to

```
{
   stage: stage,
   position: position // with the correct range
}
```

Comment: this is really good question. Can you make a runnable snippet of your code? That would be nice and easy to debug.

Comment: Set the position value to 0 for the first, 1 for the 2nd, 2 for the 3rd etc. and then when you've finished run through the array and subtract `array.length / 2` from each position.

Comment: @VicJordan I will provide it :)

Comment: `All I want to do is to map each object` - a high indication to use the **.map** function (See accepted answer) :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do that with two nested `maps`:

```js
const distanceLevels = [
  [{
    "id": 1
  }, {
    "id": 8
  }],
  [{
    "id": 2
  }],
  [{
    "id": 3
  }, {
    "id": 4
  }, {
    "id": 5
  }, {
    "id": 7
  }],
  [{
    "id": 6
  }]
]

const mappedLevels = distanceLevels.map(level =>
  level.map((stage, index, lvl) => (
    {...stage, position: index - (lvl.length - 1) / 2}
  ))
);

console.log(mappedLevels);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
let levels = [
  [
    {
      stage: 1
    },
    {
      stage: 2
    },
  ],
  [
    {
      stage: 1
    },
    {
      stage: 2
    },
    {
      stage: 3
    },
  ],
  [
    {
      stage: 1
    },
    {
      stage: 2
    },
    {
      stage: 3
    },
    {
      stage: 4
    },
    {
      stage: 5
    },
  ],
  [
    {
      stage: 1
    },
    {
      stage: 2
    },
  ]
]
 
levels.forEach(function(level) {
  let len = level.length,
      shift = (level.length + 1) / 2;
  level.map(function(stage, index) {
    stage.position = (index + 1) - shift;
  })
});

console.log(levels);
```